# How to keep CMake generated files?

Tags: cmake

I'm using `add_custom_command()` to generate some files. `ninja clean` removes them, as it should. One of the files is intended as a default/example implementation, to be modified by the user. It is only generated if it does not already exist. I would like for `ninja clean` not to remove this file.

I have tried a number of things but without success:

- `add_custom_target()`: CMake complains about the missing file unless I name it in `BYPRODUCTS`, but doing this also leads to removal on clean
- `set_file_properties(... GENERATED FALSE)` doesn't work because CMake complains about the file missing.
- `set_directory_properties()` failed in a similar way: "folder doesn't exist or not yet processed" (it does exist)

I previously generated the example implementation and just let the user copy it or model their code on it. This works, but isn't entirely satisfactory. Is my use-case so unlikely that CMake doesn't support it?

Comment: Hi Alan, welcome to SO! Good first question.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you requirment (conceptually, have `make` create something which `make clean` does not remove) *is* rather unusual. I can think of two potential solutions/workarounds.

**One**, move the file's generation to CMake time. That is, create it using `execute_process()` instead of `add_custom_command()`. This may or may not be possible, based on whether the file-generation process (the current custom command) depends on the rest of the build or not.

**Two**, totally hide the example file's existence from CMake. That is, have the custom command also generate some other file (maybe just a timestamp file) and have its driving custom target depend on that one instead. Do not list the example file as ither the custom command's dependency, output, or byproduct. That way, nothing will depend on it and neither CMake nor Ninja should not care whether it exists or not, so they will not complain or try to clean it up.

Comment: I tried something like option Two, I think. The file in question is also added to the project sources so it gets compiled. CMake complains that it can't find the file - it does not yet exist - unless I list it as an output or byproduct. Oh well... this feature is not essential. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that creating the file so that it is not removed by ninja is straightforward. But then adding it to the build before the file is physically present is hard. On the other hand, creating a file which *will* be removed is easy to add to the build, because CMake knows it is generated and will be present when needed. This seems like a lacuna in CMake's capabilities to me. We'd just need an optional flag on each OUTPUT file in add_custom_command() that says NO_CLEAN or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an example for the user, it should not be in your build folder, but in the install folder.  I don't see why you would need `add_custom_command` or the other commands you listed.

Therefore, you have to provide [install()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html#files) instructions.
You can then call `make install`. Cleaning will not remove those and only installing again will overwrite them if necessary.

Comment: This is a code generator for application developers. The tool is invoked on a file containing a description of a finite state machine (the developer maintains this file). The tool generates a number of outputs to implement the transitions, create a state chart image, and so on. The developer is then required to implement the action functions and guards. As a convenience, I thought it would be helpful to generate an initial implementation file for these, but not  to overwrite it later. This has the advantage of the project compiling after adding a new FSM descriptor.

Comment: @AlanChambers I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but it seems like you want to use CMake for something that it is not intended for.

Answer (score 0):

For those, who come here a long time after the original question was asked (like me), I'll write my solution:

The tool called in `add_custom_command` generates two files with identical content:

- one that is saved in sources, never mentioned anywhere
- and one that's marked as byproduct, and then is depended on

So the first one is the file we wanted in the first place.
And the second one is actually used in build process, and gets deleted on clean.

For me the issue is that I actually want to save generated files in VCS so I can track changes. And this approach gives ne what I need.